# I am not able to completely understand the derivation of the thermodynamic relation $C_p - C_v = R$

Tags: thermodynamics

> $$\Delta Q = \Delta U + P\Delta V = \Delta U + \Delta W$$
>
> At constant volume,
>
> $$\Delta V = 0$$  $$\Delta W = P \Delta V = 0$$ $$\Delta Q = \Delta  U$$ $$\Delta Q = n C_V \Delta T = \Delta U$$
>
> At constant pressure,
>
> $$P\Delta V = nR\Delta T$$ $$\Delta W=P \Delta V = n R \Delta T$$ $$\Delta Q = \Delta U+nR \Delta T$$ $$\Delta Q=n C_P \Delta T = \Delta U + nR\Delta T$$
>
> Now for *n*=1 mole,
>
> $\Delta U = C_V \Delta T$  
>  & 
>   $C_P \Delta T = \Delta U + R\Delta T$
>
> $\implies$
>
> $\frac{\Delta U}{\Delta T} = C_V$ $\to$ (1) 
>  & 
>  $C_P - \frac{\Delta U}{\Delta T} = R$ $\to$ (2)
>
> from (1) & (2),
>
> $C_P - C_V = R$

This is the derivation usually found everywhere.

Here, I am unable to understand how  $ \Delta U/ \Delta T = C_v$ in (1) replaces/substitutes $ \Delta U/ \Delta T$ in (2).

Comment: You need to format your work in MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$dQ = dU + dW = dU + PdV$, 
therefore, at constant Volume, Work done by the gas is zero, so
$dQ = dU$ 
& 
From Law Of Equipartition Of Energy, 
for '*n*' moles of an ideal gas $dU = \frac{f}{2}nRdT$

$\implies$ 
$dU = dQ = \frac{f}{2}nRdT$ (at constant volume) 
$nC_VdT = \frac{f}{2}nRdT$ 
hence, 
$C_V = \frac{f}{2}R$;

also, 
$nCpdT = \frac{f}{2}nRdT + PdV$ (at constant Pressure)

[$PdV +VdP = nRdT$; (Differentiating $PV = nRT$)]

$nCpdT = \frac{f}{2}nRdT + nRdT$
$Cp = \frac{f}{2}R + R$
hence, 
$Cp = Cv + R$

Comment: Please properly format your answers in MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

$ \Delta Q_{@constantP}$ - $ \Delta Q_{@constantV}$ = $ \Delta U_{@constantP}$ - $ \Delta U_{@constantV}$ + $P \Delta V$

Dividing both sides by $(n \Delta T)$

[Same change in temperature ($ \Delta T$) is brought in both the processes.]

$C_P - C_V$ = $ \Delta U/(n \Delta T)_{@ constant P}$ - $ \Delta U/(n \Delta T)_{@ constant V}$ + $P \Delta V/(n \Delta T)$

Now, the key point is that, for ideal gases, internal energy (U) depends on temperature only, so the $\Delta U$ in any process, whether at constant pressure or constant volume, will be the same if the change in temperature ($ \Delta T$) attained in both the processes is the same.

Hence, in the above result, the two terms for the change in internal energy w.r.t. the change in temperature ($ \Delta U/n \Delta T$)  will cancel each other, and you get,

$C_P - C_V = P \Delta V/n \Delta T$ = R

[ $P \Delta V/n \Delta T = R$ ]

Comment: Thank you for the added clarification. Now I understand it properly.